# Fundamental Solution of the Heat Equation on an Arbitrary Domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, regularity-theory-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

It is well known (cf. Evans §2.3.1) that

$$\Phi(x,t):= \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}} e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}}$$

is the fundamental solution of the heat equation on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $t>0$, i.e.,

$$\begin{aligned} \Phi_t - \Delta \Phi &= 0 & & \text{in } \mathbb{R}^n \times (0,\infty), \\
 \Phi &= \delta_0 & &\text{on } \mathbb{R}^n \times \{t=0\}. \end{aligned}$$

I often see that the fundamental solution is used on a bounded, open domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary. Sometimes it is called the fundamental solution to the heat equation on $\Omega$ with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary condition $\Gamma(x,y,t)$, i.e.,

$$\begin{aligned} \Gamma_t - \Delta \Gamma &= 0 & & \text{in } \Omega \times (0,\infty), \\
\Gamma &= 0 & &\text{on } \partial \Omega \times (0,\infty), \\
 \Gamma &= \delta_0 & &\text{on } \Omega \times \{t=0\}. \end{aligned}$$

Other times this function is called the Green function of the heat equation with Dirichlet boundary condition. But usually is not explained where this function comes from. In particular, I'm interested in the existence and regularity of such a fundamental solution. Could someone explain how one can derive these fundamental solutions or does someone know a good reference on this topic?

Comment: This particular fundamental solution can be easily derived from the Fourier transform (the derivation should be in Evans, too)

Comment: @NinadMunshi, I can only find the derivation for $\mathbb{R}^n$ in Evans.

Comment: This function is really only valid on $\Bbb{R}^n$. Deriving Green's functions for arbitrarily shaped boundaries is a nasty business. I recommend looking in a physics textbook for examples of these derivations. One popular technique you should have a look at is called the method of image charges (which you can find in Jackson Electrodynamics). Finding Green's functions as opposed to fundamental solutions is an art, not a science.